# Problems implementing a Python LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, reshape

I am having trouble understanding how to implement an LSTM NN in Keras.
My dataset consists of 15 features mapped to a single target, with observations spanning 667 times, i.e.:

```
trainX = 667 x 15
trainY = 667 x 1
```

1. What do the input arguments to the LSTM layer mean?

```
inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, features].
```

I understand Features is simply 15 but timesteps and batch confuse me. Does Timesteps refer to the number of rows to feed into the layer to update the next weight? For example, if I have a moving window of 20 times, the LSTM looks back 20 steps to update the weights at the next timestep?
Batchsize confuses me more because I have seen it set to None as a sort of hyperparameter that's optimised during training. Suppose batch=2, does this then refer to the number of timeblocks of data to feed into the layer, in my example 2 blocks of 20 timesteps?

2. Moreover, I have seen the LSTM layer be called in different manners, such as with a first input (for the n. of units) and then a tuple for the input_size=(timesteps, features)  despite the Keras documentation saying differently. What do the n. of units mean here and where is the batch number specified?

```
LSTM( no_units, input_shape=(window_size, np.shape(X)[1] )
```

Finally, once I have trained the network on the trainX, I would like to sequentially validate the result on validX, validY datasets.
In Matlab,  there is a function called predictAndUpdateState which computes predictions of the network 'net' using the input data X and updates the state of the network net for the following use of the network.

```matlab
% Walk-forward in the validation set, at each timestep the LSTM RNN outputs a prediction of the following time-step

for idx = 1:size(validY, 1)   % from first to last row of the validation set

    [net, validYhat(idx)] = predictAndUpdateState(net,validX(idx,:)');

end
```

3. I would like to know if there is a similar function in Keras to use on the RNN.

Comment: LSTMs are layers that process sequences (like text, audio, video, etc), if your data is not a sequence, you will have a hard time trying to make it with an LSTM.

Comment: my Xdata is comprised of 15 different timeseries..

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 15 different timeseries (that would be the samples dimension), what is the length of your time series?

Comment: there are 15 variables observed at 667 times

Comment: That sounds like you have a single time series, not multiple ones. You need to build time series samples from your data.

Comment: I have 15 timeseries as there are 15 features of 667 observations (column vectors) stacked into an array trainX, resulting in a training matrix with dimensions 667x15. There is one single timeseries of target variables trainY, a vector of dimension 667 X 1. Could you help with the questions?